# Limit of square root where x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to calculate the following limit, and I wondered if my solution to the question was true. Here it is:

$$\lim _{x \to -\infty} (\sqrt{(1+x+x^2)}-\sqrt{1-x+x^2})$$

Now I divide by $x^2$ and get:

$$\lim _{x \to -\infty} (\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{x}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{x}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2}})$$

I know that $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$ so I get the following:

$$\lim _{x \to -\infty} (\sqrt{0+0+1}-\sqrt{0-0+1})$$
So we get the following:

$$\lim _{x \to -\infty} (\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{1})=0$$

Is my solution correct?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean 'Now I divide by $\sqrt{x^2}$'.

Comment: when you divide by $x^2$ you have changed the actual function (since you never factored out $x^2)$ so your approach is incorrect. Instead use rationalization.

Comment: you need to rationalize. and be extra careful because $x \to -\infty$. so multiply $\frac{1}{|x|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{1+x+x^2}-\sqrt{1-x+x^2}=\frac{(1+x+x^2)-(1-x+x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+\sqrt{1-x+x^2}}$$

$$=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}+\sqrt{1-x+x^2}}\stackrel{(1)}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}+1}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}+1}}$$

$$\stackrel{x\to -\infty}\to \frac{-2}{\sqrt{0+0+1}+\sqrt{0-0+1}}=-1$$

$(1)\!\! :\,$ I divide numerator and denominator by $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ and assume $x<0$, which I can do because we only care about what happens when $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it okay to divide be x in this answer?

Comment: @Alan I divide by $|x|$. Since we only care about what happens as $x\to -\infty$, we can assume $x<0$. Also $x^2\pm x+1>0$ for any real $x$, so the expression is always defined.

Comment: @Alan Also $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, so $\frac{\sqrt{1\pm x+x^2}}{|x|}=\sqrt{\frac{1\pm x+x^2}{x^2}}$.

Comment: If $x<0$ then you can not input it in the square-root,... @ user31415

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 I divide by $|x|$. Read above comment: $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, so $\frac{\sqrt{1\pm x+x^2}}{|x|}=\sqrt{\frac{1\pm x+x^2}{x^2}}$, because $1\pm x + x^2>0,\, x^2>0$, so the square root division property can be used.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't at all.

What you have shown is that

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{x}=0$$

because you have divided the function of that you were computing the limit by $x$.

To compute limits like this, it is customary to multiply and divide by an expression with the same roots, but added.

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-x+1}\right)\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}$$

Comment: How it will $0$ ?? Please show your calculation...

Answer (score -1):

No. First, you divided by $x^2$ inside the square roots, which means you divided the whole expression by $|x|$. So you have shown that the difference of the square roots, *divided by $x$*, goes to zero.

Here's a hint: Multiply and divide the expression by the sum of the two square roots.